# Select and deselect piece to move mode in Arena

Tags: arena

In Arena I select one field with piece I want to move or click some field accidentaly. Suppose after that I changed my mind and want to make move by other piece, now when I click new piece nothing happens and I have to find what field is selected and deselect it first by clicking on it. This mode is very annoying for me. How can I switch it off? I want to select new piece to move just by clicking it once.

Comment: What you wish to do is impossible in Arena.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, this is a very annoying issue indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there may be a solution for your problem, I suggest you get used to it instead, as it follows the official laws of chess and deters you from doing otherwise.

> 4.3 Except as providedin Article 4.2, if the player having the move deliberately touches on the chessboard:
>
> a. one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched which can be moved

Good practice for visualization and proper chess etiquette.

Source: https://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=124&view=article